# Allow Full Calendar Event resizing upto a particular interval of time

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar plugin. Trying to do event resize. I need to resize the event say  upto a full day, not another day. when the resizing is done upwards that is towards the starttime it should be till 30m after start time.

How is it possible. 
I don't find any options for this full calendar event resize callback functions.(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResizeStart/).

Comment: Would you please add some of your code? I am not sure I understand what you mean when you say "it should be till 30 mins after start time". Also have you looked at the other callbacks? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/ http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResizeStop/

Comment: @MarCrazyness: Yes I have looked at the callback functions. But there are no options to restrict resize upto a time before start time. Suppose my start time is 3:30pm. My end time is 5pm. Then the end time should be only resizable to 4.00pm(or) or down to till that day. I haven't written any code for this in event resize. I am confused at how to start also to restrict the resize handler.

Comment: Ah so you want to restrict the duration of an event, and give the ability to have events that are only 30 mins long? If that is the case I would calculate the duration in the eventResize callback, if it is more than 30 mins then change the end date/time to (start date time + 30 mins) and throw an error. Sounds like a cool feature to limit duration, like event max duration or something. I would say its worth requesting :)

Comment: @MarCrazyness: Thank you for the suggestion. I am placing any ohter restrictions in eventResize. I didn't check before that full calendar is allowing the resize like the way I wanted only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event resize is allowed  in fullcalendar for week view and day view for 30minutes only say till starttime+30minutes and till the end of day. This is what I wanted.

I have checked it before.
In month view only  days can be increased. I don't want this resize feature in month view So I have just disabled it using css (or) we can also remove the resize handler in eventRender Function.

If we want to place any restrictions we can do those in eventResize function.